# Rails has_many through association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models:

```
sophead
od 
od_item
```

**sophead** has many **ods** and
**od** has many **od_items**.

each **od_item** belongs to one **od** and each **od** belongs to one **sophead**

I want to be able to return all **od_items** for a specific **sophead** like this:

```
all_od_items_for_first_sophead = Sophead.first.od_items
```

what is the correct association for getting all the **od_item**s for a **sophead**?

I had tried:

```
has_many :od_items, through: :ods
```

but I believe that this is incorrect as it doesn't really match [this diagram](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)  - in that diagram's example (with different model names), the arrow from patients to appointments would run the other direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Type of association does not matter, above is also correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try was correct way to do it.
Your models must have associations like this:

models/sophead.rb

```
class Sophead < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ods
  has_many :od_items, through: :ods
end
```

models/od.rb

```
class Od < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sophead
  has_many :od_items
end
```

models/od_item.rb

```
class OdItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :od
end
```